# PHP CMS inside a Liferay portlet

Tags: php, drupal, content-management-system, portlet, liferay

Is it possible to deploy a PHP CMS inside a Liferay portlet?

I know it's possible to create php portlets but i was wondering about a whole php application, or to be more specific, a cms like drupal.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not possible.